# VNC server stops running after a while

Tags: vnc, vncserver, digital-ocean

I have a little problem, I have a VNC server running on Digitalocean. This works, I can connect to it with no problems. But after a while (maybe a couple of days after the last connect or something) I try to connect again and it says the VNC server is not running. Only after I turn it on manually it works again.

Is there some sort of way to keep the VNC server always running? I hope there is.

Thanks in advance!
- Nick van Kesteren

Comment: Please add more details about your deployment, like what OS you are using, what VNC server and how did you install it, etc. At first glance it looks like you might need to configure your VNC server as [a service that is restarted when it crashes](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples).

Comment: @npclaudiu Oh of course, I forgot to add those! I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. At the moment I have the smallest droplet that Digitalocean offers. I have fully installed it via this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04
I will try to add it as a service that restarts, thanks!